# Why my code don't return the size of my arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, android, opencv

My code reads an image and saves the value of the pixels in an array of type double []. However, I needed a dynamic size, so I created an arraylist and added the array inside the arraylist. The problem is that I can not get the size of the array nor get any information from the arraylist. It simply does not show me anything. What's the problem? See my code below.

```
Java for android

public class img_pixel {
    String src = "path_of_image.jpg";
    Mat imgRead = Imgcodecs.imread(src, IMREAD_COLOR); //read a image
    int row = imgRead.rows(); //get the number of rows
    int col = imgRead.cols(); //get the number of cols

    List <double[]> pixels = new ArrayList<>(); //Arraylist 

    public void cor() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                double[] rgb = imgRead.get(i, j); //array with information i, j
                pixels.add(0, rgb);
            }
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < pixels.size(); x++) { // for to get size of arraylist
            Log.v("Size", "Size:" + pixels.get(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < lin; i++) {` where is `lin` ?

Comment: `pixels.get(x)` returns a `double[]`. Converting a `double[]` into `String` results in something like `"[I@23fc4bec"`.

Comment: What is the variable lin?

Comment: the lin variable and col were replaced by row and col is that had already copied the code here so I did not realize I'm sorry. I edited.

Comment: @Turing85 How I can return in integer? Inside of arraylist there is pixels value... I want to see this values.

Answer (score 1):

Your question indicates a lack of understanding of how arraylist or arrays work.

1. Your code already "gets" the arraylist size. In your second for loop, you call `pixels.size()`. That method returns the length of the arraylist. So, you are wrong about "nor get any information from the arraylist".
2. It seems what you want to know is the size of of the array for *each* pixel. I'm not sure why, given that it will be the same for each one for a given image, but lets move past that. In your code, you have `Log.v("Size", "Size:"+pixels.get(x));` which I assume is your attempt to get the array size. However, pixels.get(x) only returns an array object, so it appears you are attempting to convert something of type `double []` to a string and expecting to see an array size. Do you see the problem? If you want the "size" (which I assume you mean "length") of the array, you need to use the length property, for example `pixels.get(x).length`. If you actually want the size, you'll need to do more work. I suggest figuring out what information you actually want then do some research like "how to get the size of an array in Java".

Comment: and any tips for me to do to see the data (pixels) that are inside the arraylist "pixels"?

Comment: @BDamsk I suggest finding some tutorials which have sample code that cover what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the size of the double array in the position x of the arraylist just call somethink like

```
pixels.get(x).length;
```

But I'm sorry I'm not sure to understand the question well!

Comment: I solved. Thanks. the logs don't appear because I don't had inicialized the class img_pixel in the main class.